# A function defined in first js file does not working in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="test1.js"></script>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

test1. js is

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  alert('hello');
function check(){
    alert('hello i should also appear'); }
 });
```

And test2.js is

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

 check();
  });
```

`hello` is alerting , but `hello i should also appear` is not alerting , Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here.
  thanks in advannce

Comment: Its in ready-scope. Put check outside ready.

Comment: In addition to the posted answers - note that this is nothing to do with multiple files - you could have all your code in one file and see the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under test1.js please write you function out of document.ready. functions which are written inside the document.ready cannot be accessed from out side. So you have to move it out from document.ready

```
function check(){
  alert('hello i should also appear'); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is defined inside of an anonymous `function(){}`, so it can be called just inside of its scope.

You should fix it and define the function outside of it:

```
// now it will be visible everywhere
var check;


$(document).ready(function(){

  alert('hello');
  check = function (param){
    alert('hello i should also appear. Param passed is ' + param); }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined "check" in a closure passed to the first call to document.ready(). The closure passed to the second call to document.ready() does not have access to the scope of the first closure, and in this particular case the function "check" only stays around for as long as the closure it is defined within.

You need to move your check function out of the closure and to a higher lexical scope where both closures can access it.

Answer (score 0):

you should write function as global. If you write in `document.ready()` then that function scope limited so you cant access it from another javascript file

Answer (score 0):

Change *test1.js* to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
});
function check() {
    alert('hello i should also appear');
}
```

and be sure to load *test1.js* before you load *test2.js*.